# How to replace a word in a file with a word in another file in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to change a word in a file, with another word that I get from another file.

Let's say I have 2 files :

File #1 contains : jack
File #2 contains : Hello name

How can I replace the word "name" with "jack"?
PS. File #1 contains only this word, no need for any regex.

Comment: A pure `sed` solution is impossible, because `sed` is not able to take information from a file to another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shell command will do the replacement using Perl:

```
NAME="$(cat file1)" perl -pi -e 's@name@$ENV{NAME}@g' file2
```

An alternative with Perl:

```
perl -pi -e "s@name@$(cat file1)@g" file2
```

An alternative with `sed`, using `-i` to modify the file in place:

```
sed -i "s@name@$(cat file1)@g" file2
```

All of the solutions above assume that `file1` doesn't contain newlines (except possibly for the trailing newline), backslashes and at signs (`@`).

If you want a pure `sed` solution opens both `file1` and `file2` itself (rather then relying on the shell or `cat` to open files), then it's probably impossible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the sed command works like a charm. I will just replace the new file with the old one then.

Comment: it is possible to read file contents in sed using `r` command, which is robust even if file contains newlines and such... replacing partial line is tricky though, can be done if string `Hello` is known and unique... `sed -e '/name/r file1' -e 's///' file2 | sed '/Hello/{N; s/\n//}'` .. also why use temp  file out when sed supports `-i`? `sed -i "s@name@$(< file1)@g" file2`

Answer (score 3):

Good grief, just use awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{name=$0; next} {sub(/name/,name); print}' file1 file2
```

Comment: but is it possible to replace it inside the same file?
For example I tried adding ' ... > file2 ' but it emptied the file, and with trying '... >> file2 ' i get the right text appended to the end of the file, So is there a way?